# Keyboard Maestro. How to select a file in an "Open file" dialog?

Tags: macos, automation, keyboard-maestro

I want to automate search by an image using [Google's image search](https://www.google.com/imghp). I was able to automate saving screenshot to a file and opening a page with Google image search. And now I want to select the saved file in the "Choose file" dialog.
How can I automate this?

[image: Choose file dialog]

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I was able to do this by using simulation of the `CMD + SHIFT + G` keystroke and pasting a path to the screenshot.
[Here is my final macro](https://gist.github.com/dvdvdmt/874a991fce2638c9ac720c589496264d)
[image]